# LINQ Product of two fields in aggregated query

Tags: linq, grouping, field, product

I need to calculate a sum of product of two fields. This will be used for average weighted price.
avgPrice = sum( price*volume) / sum(volume). Both price1 and price2  return error "Specified cast is not valid."

```
     var result3 = from sym in dataTableAsEnumerable()
                   group sym by new { symbol = sym["symbol"] } into grouped
                   select new
                   {
                      //             SYMBOL = sym.Field<string>("symbolCAN"),
                      SYMBOL = grouped.Key.symbol,
                      tradeTimeMin = grouped.Min(e => e["tradeTimeMin"]),
                      tradeTimeMax = grouped.Max(e => e["tradeTimeMax"]),
                      volume = grouped.Sum(e => (int)e["volume"] ),
                      price1 = grouped.Sum(e => (double)e["volume"] * (double)e["symbol"]) / grouped.Sum(e => (double)e["volume"]),
                      price2 = grouped.Sum(e => ( e.Field<decimal>("volume") * e.Field<decimal>("symbol")))


                   };
```

Comment: What happens if you set volume = grouped.Sum(e => (decimal)e["volume"])? or if you set volume = grouped.Sum(e => (decimal)e["symbol"])? Do you still get the cast error?

Comment: Hi,
the query works well for a single field. I can get grouped.Sum(e => (decimal)e["volume"]) without problems. What I cannot do is to get a product, division or a sum of values from two fields. That is I cannot get  sum( volume * price). I wish to use LINQ to calculated averages and aggregated values other than simple sum,min and max over a single field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is related to getting the values out of the `DataRow`. It looks like `volume` is an `int` and `symbol` is a `double`, but in your error lines you're using one or the other as a different type. A comparable example would be trying to do this:

```
object o = 3.0; // double
decimal m = (decimal)o;
```

This will fail because you're trying to unbox a `double` as a `decimal`. On the other hand, this works fine:

```
object o = 3.0; // double
double d = (double)o;
decimal m = (decimal)d;
```

To fix your example, you need to first cast the value to the correct type, then cast accordingly (or just fall back on implicit casts):

```
    ...
    price = grouped.Sum(e => e.Field<int>("volume") * e.Field<double>("symbol")) /
            grouped.Sum(e => e.Field<int>("volume"))
    ...
```

Or using an anonymous type to make your final select more readable:

```
...
let data = grouped.Select(e => new {
   Volume = e.Field<int>("volume"),
   Symbol = e.Field<double>("symbol")
})
select new
{
    ...
    price = data.Sum(x => x.Volume * x.Symbol) / data.Sum(x => x.Volume)
    ...
};
```

Comment: Hi dahlbyk. Thank you for your answer. I was indeed mixing types.

This worked well:

                          averagePrice = grouped.Sum(e => (e.Field<int>("volume") * e.Field<decimal>("price"))) / grouped.Sum(e => (int)e["volume"])

Comment: Glad to help. For your future reference, the Field<T> extension method is really only useful for nullable types because it handles DBNull. For value types, you might as well just cast directly.

Comment: Well, as you might have noticed, I am brand new in LINQ. Just trying to complete a project. To understand more complex concepts, I will need to do some serious learning. Your answer helped me over the first bump. Thanks again, Sin.